# google search index what is fresh content

Tags: google-search, google-index

I read that sites have good reputation in google search index if it is fresh content.

what does fresh content means from google's point of view?

I have many pages. I have created articles and tutorials.

These page dosent change except the comments which are at the bottom.

I have made this page as static (.html) and never edit cause that is the information i wanted to be ever. cause the concept is not going to change?

with these parameters how to judge whether my page is fresh or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fresh Content in the eyes of Google isn't just about uniqueness while this is an important factor because if your content isn't unique then its definitely not fresh and more duplicate content.

It's not 100% certain how Google factors fresh content but here's what the SEO scene believe to be close to how Google Factors fresh content into its algorithms.

But to give you an example how fresh content plays out take the following topics into consideration and ask yourself would you rather an old page for the search or aged....

- Things going Viral, Recent News and Events, Current Trends
- Reoccurring Events/News such as Lottery Numbers
- Recurring updates to pages such as reviews

Fresh content means actually  what it means... Its Fresh... So if you have a page dated today.. it's fresh, after time it will become aged and not so fresh..... If you have constant people leaving comments on the page then this can be considered fresh, or if you revisit the page and update it week or monthly then it becomes fresh again...

I recommend you take a look at [How Fresh Content Can Influence Rankings](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-fresh-factor)...

Answer (score 1):

Generally Fresh content is about unique text, at least 60-70% unique. So when people are posting blog articles google compares them to existing content through out the web to see if it's unique. If it's not unique google will not index it. If you are looking at a page with active comments on it where the base content was unique and your comments are being added to it google will just update the page's metrics as to what keywords to show up for if the comments make the page more relevant to new keywords. generally speaking though comments aren't as valuable as new pages with new content.